# JFileChooser: checkbox selection

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jfilechooser

I'm currently trying to automate regex usage (match/replace-pairs) on a **huge** number of files by writing a small application that allows the selection of files, regexes, etc. Therefore, the user should (obviously) be able to select files, a purpose for which I am using the `JFileChooser` provided by `javax.swing.JFileChooser`.

Now, while this is basically working so far, I would like the selection to be via checkboxes, as possible in the default windows explorer (see screenshot below).

Is this possible with the default `JFileChooser`? Or would I have to write a (for this purpose potentially too complex) custom `JFileChooser`?

Any help appreciated!

[image: Screenshot: checkbox selection in Windows]

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for some ideas.

Comment: You cannot use JFileChooser for this, it only lets you change the icons which are displayed for the different file extensions.

Comment: from what I can tell by looking [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074920/learn-java/enterprise-application-integration-customizing-swing-s-file-chooser.html), what I want to do (without creating a whole new class independent from `JFileChooser`) _should_ be possible with `setAccessory` in the `FileView` class that can be set for a file chooser. I'll probably give it a try later and let you know what I found.

Comment: Update: I'll probably use `JFileChooser` only for selecting the directory, then implement the file selection via a `JTable` by displaying the files as `(/folder)*/file.java` (<- regex). If I remember correctly from the last time I used tables, it should be possible to display table row selection via checkboxes. Anyways, this whole solution is closer to what I had in mind than using a filechooser, which opens a separate window.